# Macro does not recognize some queries

Tags: excel, vba

For some reason some queries are recognized as Requests and some other as queries in my workbook.
[image: Existing connection picture]

This difference prevents me from refreshing the concerned queries in the following way :

```
Sub Start()
    If Verification Then
        Key = MsgBox("Please close all other Excel file, are you ready?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Export loader")
        If Key = vbYes Then
                ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Extract").Refresh // (this one is working)
                    DoEvents
                ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Regiments").Refresh // (I tried this way)
                ThisWorkbook.Connections("Requête - Regiments").Refresh  // (and also this one)
                    DoEvents
                ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Formations").Refresh // (I tried this way)
                ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Formations").Refresh // (and also this one)
                    DoEvents
            MsgBox "End of the process", , "End"
        Else
            MsgBox "Abort", , "Abort Procedure"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I always got this error popup message :

> (Run time error 9) - Subscript out of range

My queries don't have anything special ... here they are :

-REGIMENTS

```
let
    Annuaire = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ANNUAIRE"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    Year = Number.FromText(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Year"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]),
    Month = Number.FromText(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Month"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]),

    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(Annuaire), null, true),

    MyTable = Source{[Item="Annuaire régiments",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(MyTable),
    #"Colonnes renommées" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Promoted Headers",{{"code ES", "code es"}}),
    #"Type modifié" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Colonnes renommées",{{"code es", type text}}),
    #"Personnalisée ajoutée" = Table.AddColumn(#"Type modifié", "code ES", each if Text.Length([code es]) < 7 then "0" & [code es] else [code es]),
    #"Colonnes supprimées" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Personnalisée ajoutée",{"code es"}),
    #"Colonnes permutées1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Colonnes supprimées",{"Intitulé court", "Intitulé long", "code ES", "Type"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colonnes permutées1", "Intitulé", each "[" & [code ES] & "] - " & [Intitulé court]),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Intitulé court", "Intitulé", "Intitulé long", "code ES", "Type"}),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{"Intitulé court"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns2",{{"Intitulé", type text}, {"Intitulé long", type text}, {"code ES", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"Intitulé long"}),
    #"Invoked Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Pose de TAG", each #"Nbr-Scanne-Mensuel"([code ES], Month, Year)),
    
    #"Invoked Scanne" = Table.AddColumn(#"Invoked Month", "code scanné", each #"CumulEtScanne-Regiment"([code ES], 1)),
    #"Invoked GeoLoca" = Table.AddColumn(#"Invoked Scanne", "Code Géolocalisé", each #"Nbr-Scanne-Geo-Regiment"([code ES])),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Invoked GeoLoca",{"code ES", "Type"}),
    #"Colonnes permutées" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns1",{"Intitulé", "Pose de TAG", "code scanné", "Code Géolocalisé"})
in
    #"Colonnes permutées"
```

-FORMATIONS

```
let
    Annuaire = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ANNUAIRE"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    Year = Number.FromText(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Year"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]),
    Month = Number.FromText(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Month"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]),

    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(Annuaire), null, true),

    MyTable = Source{[Item="Annuaire Formation",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(MyTable),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Promoted Headers", "Intitulé", each "[" & [code ES] & "] - " & [Intitulé court]),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Intitulé court", "Intitulé", "Intitulé long", "code ES", "Type"}),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{"Intitulé court"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns2",{{"Intitulé", type text}, {"Intitulé long", type text}, {"code ES", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"Intitulé long"}),

    #"Invoked Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Pose de TAG", each #"Nbr-Scanne-Mensuel"([code ES], Month, Year)),
    
    #"Invoked Scanne" = Table.AddColumn(#"Invoked Month", "code scanné", each #"CumulEtScanne-Regiment"([code ES], 1)),
    #"Invoked GeoLoca" = Table.AddColumn(#"Invoked Scanne", "Code Géolocalisé", each #"Nbr-Scanne-Geo-Regiment"([code ES])),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Invoked GeoLoca",{"code ES", "Type"}),
    #"Colonnes permutées" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns1",{"Intitulé", "Pose de TAG", "code scanné", "Code Géolocalisé"})
in
    #"Colonnes permutées"
```

- EXTRACT

```
let
    HistoLoca = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="HISTOLOCA"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    Annuaire = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="HISTOLOCA"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    Year = Number.FromText(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Year"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]),
    Month = Number.FromText(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Month"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]),

    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(Annuaire),[Delimiter=";", Columns=21, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Date Historique", type text}, {"Code EPC", type text}, {"Code TID", type text}, {"Code EMAT8", type text}, {"NumÃ©ro individualisation (MCI)", type text}, {"NumÃ©ro de sÃ©rie", type text}, {"NumÃ©ro AISM", type text}, {"Code ASM", type text}, {"Processus fonctionnel", type text}, {"Date de relevÃ©", type text}, {"Heure de relevÃ©", type time}, {"Pseudonyme", type text}, {"Nom", type text}, {"PrÃ©nom", type text}, {"Grade", type text}, {"CoordonnÃ©es X", Int64.Type}, {"CoordonnÃ©es Y", Int64.Type}, {"ES dÃ©tenteur", type text}, {"LibellÃ© ES dÃ©tenteur", type text}, {"ES situation", type text}, {"LibellÃ© ES situation", type text}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"NumÃ©ro individualisation (MCI)", "Numéro individualisation (MCI)"}, {"NumÃ©ro de sÃ©rie", "Numéro de série"}, {"NumÃ©ro AISM", "Numéro AISM"}, {"Date de relevÃ©", "Date de relevé"}, {"Heure de relevÃ©", "Heure de relevé"}, {"PrÃ©nom", "Prénom"}, {"CoordonnÃ©es X", "Coordonnées X"}, {"CoordonnÃ©es Y", "Coordonnées Y"}, {"ES dÃ©tenteur", "ES détenteur"}, {"LibellÃ© ES dÃ©tenteur", "Libellé ES détenteur"}, {"LibellÃ© ES situation", "Libellé ES situation"}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Date Histo", each #date(Number.FromText(Text.AfterDelimiter([Date Historique], "/", 1)), Number.FromText(Text.BetweenDelimiters([Date Historique], "/", "/")), Number.FromText(Text.BeforeDelimiter([Date Historique], "/")))),
    #"Added Custom01" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Date relevé", each #date(Number.FromText(Text.AfterDelimiter([Date de relevé], "/", 1)), Number.FromText(Text.BetweenDelimiters([Date de relevé], "/", "/")), Number.FromText(Text.BeforeDelimiter([Date de relevé], "/")))),
    #"Reordered Columns1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Custom01",{"Date Histo", "Date Historique", "Code EPC", "Code TID", "Code EMAT8", "Numéro individualisation (MCI)", "Numéro de série", "Numéro AISM", "Code ASM", "Processus fonctionnel", "Date de relevé", "Date relevé", "Heure de relevé", "Pseudonyme", "Nom", "Prénom", "Grade", "Coordonnées X", "Coordonnées Y", "ES détenteur", "Libellé ES détenteur", "ES situation", "Libellé ES situation"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Reordered Columns1",{{"Date Histo", type date},{"Date relevé", type date}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"Date Historique", "Date de relevé"}),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Date Histo", "Date Historique"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns1"
```

I really don't understand why there is "Query" and "Requête" ... I made them the same way

Comment: Looks to me as if some of the queries where made with an english and some with a french Excel instance. Can imagine that your problem comes from the special character `ê` in the name. Have you tried to access the queries via index like `ThisWorkbook.Connections(1)`? Loop over all queries and dump the name to the immediate window using `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Connections(i).name`

Comment: Thank you for your speed and efficiency. Your solution works well. The french translation of Excel is a real issue ...